# System.UnauthorizedAccessException while deleting dll (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, io

Please read carefully: I know that dlls can be in use. I also know about NTFS permissions, and read-only flag.

1. I create a *text* file with content hello.
2. I rename it to .dll
3. I try to use `File.Delete(...)` method to delete it: I got 
   `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`
4. I try to open it with `File.OpenWrite(...)` I got the same exception.
5. I've turned out *all* virus checking software.
6. I am admin in my Windows 7 machine.
7. I am the owner of the .dll extension file
8. I can it delete without any warning from the UI.

Using VS 2012 C# program (.NET 4.5)

Any ideas?
Thanks

---

SOLVED: (partly): This was my firewall :-(.  Somehow it cached and *sandboxed* my project output executable, and restricted to delete .dlls (not .txts). Although I turned off it, and I rebuild the .exe many times somehow the named exe sandboxed state remained active. I stress it was a many times rebuild and binary changed .exe. Congratulations to Commodo just 2 erratic behaviour in on issue. 1) Why the sandboxing is still active if antivirus has turned off? 2) Why not reevaluate the named .exe file and asking me about sandboxing if the binary has changed? How this is turned out? I renamed the project output to x.exe :-(

This was more the 45 minutes from my life and worktime...

Comment: can you delete it if you don't name it to dll?

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu : he said that at the end of the text : yes.
Have you tried changing your file extension to 'txt" and then deleting it ?

Comment: Can you show the code? have you used Process Explorer to see if there's a handle on the file?

Comment: @losSebos where does he say that he can delete the file without the dll extension?

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu : "I can it delete without any warning from the UI." line 8

Comment: @losSebos first: he is talking about deleting it from UI there, and the context of this question is code. second: he is able to delete the dll extension, he didn't say anything about txt. it is completely irrelevant to my comment. please first try to understand the comments before replying next time.

Comment: sorry i thought you were talking about deleting it manualy..be more precise next time

Comment: More clarifications: Do you have User Access Control enabled? Is it possible you've set Windows Explorer to automatically elevate privileges, while your code has no such permissions?

Comment: Hi guys, thx for active brainstorming: 1) I have no uses access controll enabled, this is a hardcore dev machine. 2) I've changed the program itself to look for .txt file, and it works like a charm. To summarize: The issue is occurs _only_ if I try to delete a .dll extension file from .NET / C# code.

Answer (score 0):

For delete try

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: I clearly stated: I know about attributes. The issue is only occurs when the file extension is .dll, even the case if it is a fake dll, which never was used/loaded by the system.